# How can I identify and install missing character sets for browsers?

Tags: windows-7, windows, fonts, character-encoding

In Chrome, Firefox and IE, when looking at certain webpages, I get placeholder characters for some characters that cannot be displayed.

Chrome:
[image]

Firefox:
[image]

IE:
[image]

When I open the URL in Microsoft Word, it shows the characters:
[image]

Now my question is: *As a general rule*, how do I go about:

1. Identifying what character sets these are that are missing?
2. Installing the missing character sets so the browsers display them?

Just as an aside: Why, if Word can display them, can none of the browsers on my system?

(The page, just for reference, is here: http://slavenorth.com/columns/oldenglish.htm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a problem with character encoding, not a font issue. The web page mentioned is served with an HTTP header that says `Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8`, declaring the page to be UTF-8 encoded. It is in fact Windows-1252 encoding; that encoding used to be the one commonly used when the page was created (around 2002). The “�” symbols indicate data errors at the *character* level (byte strings that do not denote any character in the encoding being applied).

The problem should of course be fixed server-side. But as a visitor, you can instruct your browser to ignore the HTTP header and apply the right encoding instead. For this, you typically use the “View” command menu, item “Encoding” or “Character encoding” and select an alternative like “Western”, “West European”, “ISO-8895-1”, or “Windows-1252” (these all really mean the same thing in browsers).

Comment: Thanks. By way of example, in Firefox setting the encoding to "Western" (had defaulted to "Unicode") solved the problem. You are probably right then in that case that the way to resolve it is to contact the owner of the site.

Answer (score 1):

> **Identifying what character sets these are that are missing?**

Firstly, a character can exist in many character sets, I think it better to start by identifying

- what character-set is specified by the web-page itself (if none - see [default](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_charactersets.asp))
- what [Unicode script](http://www.unicode.org/charts/) contains the character

Usually, looking at the HTML page source can help identify the character set. Often the answer will be UTF-8 - which answers your question but in an unhelpful way. Ctrl+U works in most browsers, or context-menu "View page source".

To identify the character I usually paste it into an application such as gVim which allows you to interrogate it for the hex value of the character under the cursor. In Microsoft-Word you can probably highlight the character and press ALt+X to see the hex value. Then I look it up using Google e.g. "unicode character 2301".

> **Installing the missing character sets so the browsers display them?**

Generally, you don't install a character set, you install a font that contains glyphs for a range of desired characters. Nowadays you don't worry much about the font encoding. Again, I'd use Google to find e.g. "font miscellaneous technical symbol".

> **Why, if Word can display them, can none of the browsers on my system?**

Great question. Nowadays I expect browsers to use all available fonts to find a glyph for any character. <strike>Further investigation required. Maybe you could use Word save the text to a UTF-8 text file and post it somewhere or edit that text into your answer.</strike>. See [Jukka K. Korpela's answer](https://superuser.com/a/849937/52492)  ... +1 ... (sigh)

P.S. this question is a great example of an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). I only looked at the X, JK saw the Y.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answer. Google is of course good for everything, if you know what it is you are searching for :-) Anyway, hopefully this Q&A will come up in Google for the next person with this problem.

Comment: I see your point about this being an X-Y problem. As an experienced user, would you suggest I edit my question to remove the confusion? The problem is that it might make JK's answer seem a bit odd if I remove references to character sets.

Comment: @mydoghasworms: I'd leave the question unchanged.